# Run linux command from django view script

Tags: python, django, bash, pythonanywhere, avconv

I try to use avconv for my web-app (Django on pythonanywhere). I have to extract a thumbnail from a video file.
Using the bash console, I can run:

```
avconv -ss 00:01:00 -i myapp/myapp/media/inputvide.mp4 -vsync 1 -t 0.01 myapp/myapp/media/videothumb.png
```

This works fine.
When I want to use this command by script (view.py) I tried:

```
cmd = 'avconv -ss 00:01:00 -i '+inputfile+' -vsync 1 -t 0.01 '+outputfile
os.system(cmd)
```

inputfile is the path to my video and outputile is the path to my video + '.png'
There are no errors thrown, but I can not find the output file anywhere in my folders?

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: try using absolute paths?  eg `/home/yourusername/foldername/filename.thing`, not just filename.thing...

Comment: the variable input file contains the absolute path!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try with the subprocess library:

```
from subprocess import call

success = call('avconv -ss 00:01:00 -i '+inputfile+' -vsync 1 -t 0.01'+outputfile, shell=True)

if success != 0:
    //The command has failed
```